# ffmpeg audio duration increase using atrim

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I have video of duration **10** secs and with the help of following command i can trim and then concatenate it using following command:

**Video**

```
ffmpeg -y -i test_video.mp4 -filter_complex \
"[0:v]split=3[outvideo1][outvideo2][outvideo3]; \
[outvideo1]trim=0:2,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[video1]; \
[outvideo2]trim=2:8,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[video2]; \
[outvideo3]trim=start=8,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[video3]; \
[video1][video2][video3]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0[outvideo]" \
-map '[outvideo]' test_video_text.mp4
```

Result of above **Video** command is fine and duration of test_video_text.mp4 is also **10** secs

But when using the above command for audio as below:

**Audio**

```
ffmpeg -y -i test_video.mp4 -filter_complex \
"[0:a]asplit=3[outaudio1][outaudio2][outaudio3]; \
[outaudio1]atrim=0:2,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[audio1]; \
[outaudio2]atrim=2:8,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[audio2]; \
[outaudio3]atrim=start=8,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[audio3]; \
[audio1][audio2][audio3]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1[outaudio]" \
-map '[outaudio]' test_video_text.mp3
```

The duration of test_video_text.mp3 increases from **10** secs to **20** secs having **silence** after first **10** secs.

Here is the console output for audio:

```
ffmpeg version 3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.0.1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-opencl --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libxvid --enable-libfreetype --enable-vda
  libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
  libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
  libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
  libavresample   3.  0.  0 /  3.  0.  0
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'test_video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: mp41mp42isom
    creation_time   : 2015-09-24 18:32:33
  Duration: 00:00:09.87, start: 0.068254, bitrate: 235 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 320x320, 183 kb/s, 29.67 fps, 29.67 tbr, 29673 tbn, 59.35 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-09-24 18:32:33
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (HE-AAC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 48 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-09-24 18:32:33
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
Output #0, mp3, to 'test_video_text.mp3':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: mp41mp42isom
    TSSE            : Lavf57.25.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.24.102 libmp3lame
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 (aac) -> asplit
  concat -> Stream #0:0 (libmp3lame)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
size=     156kB time=00:00:09.95 bitrate= 128.6kbits/s speed=63.7x    
video:0kB audio:156kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.219216%
```

**Note:**
Even i remove **asetpts** for audio command the result is same having **20** secs duration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an encoding bug, but one related to MP3 metadata i.e. FFmpeg isn't encoding 20 seconds of audio. Insert `-write_xing 0`. The correct duration should be displayed.

Comment: you are genius !!

Comment: how can we use in this case `-map '[outvideo]' -map '[outaudio]' -write_xing 0 test.mp4` ? for outaudio audio stream

Comment: Shouldn't need that option for MP4.